# How to run TypeScript compiler not in CLI

Tags: typescript

Here's a CLI command to build TypeScript:

```sh
tsc -w --outDir lib
```

How can I run this in Node, ideally concurrently? I'm looking for something like this:

```js
import typescript from 'typescript';

typescript({
  watch: true,
  outDir: 'lib/',
}).on('error', (e) => console.log(e));
```

Here's what I've tried:

1. `exec('tsc -w --outDir lib')`: have to parse stdout to get errors / successes
2. `gulp-typescript`: does not warm rebuild as fast as `tsc -w`

Comment: "How can I run this in JavaScript" - depends on how you want to run it - in a browser? In a Node host? Etc?

Comment: I've updated the question to mention Node specifically.